# Using Real-time Updates with a callback that requires auth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time, http-authentication

I'm trying to setup [real-time](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) updates in my server and it looks like it only works with URLs that don't require authentication.

Does anyone knows how to make it work with HTTP auth?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. Facebook specifies that they need public access to the callback server.  They will send the information in a signed format that only you can decrypt since you are the only one who has the private (aka secret) key.  So you have no need to put any http auth on the callback URL.